# How to rollback mongodb using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an array as below.

```
const array = 
[
  { name: 'Tom',
    age: '30'
  },
  { name: 'Sam',
    age: '24'
  }
]
```

And I create this array using mongoose.

```
Schema.create(array)
```

'name' and 'age' are required. Therefore in this case, they are created well.
But When I put this array,

```
const array = 
[
  { name: 'Tom',
    age: '30'
  },
  { name: 'Sam'}
]
```

Tom is created but Sam is not created as it doesn' t have age value.
When one of those has an error during create, I want to not save nothing at all.
It's becuase 'front client' have to try insert again when receiving error response.
How can I control transaction using mongo and mongoose? Thank you for reading it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Schema model` for that and add `required` to it :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const myUserSchema = new Schema ({
    users : [{
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        age: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }]
})
var myUser = mongoose.model('myUser', myUserSchema)
```

Then:

```
const array = 
[
  { name: 'Tom',
    age: '30'
  },
  { name: 'Sam'}
]

const newUser = new myUser({
  users: array
})
newUser.save((err, user)=>{
 if (err) {
   console.log(err)
 }
})
```

It should validate your array at the time when you try to save it and throw an error in case if something is missing.

Example of thrown error:

```
ValidationError: myUser validation failed: users.1.age: Path `age` is required
```